# How to delete user accounts from Google

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have four Google accounts but I only use two of them. I'd like to delete the other two but all four show when I click the blue sign in from `google.com`.

How can I delete the two I don't use and make my main email the default?

<sub>I've logged out as each user. In Settings, only my main email shows up so I can't delete it from there.</sub>

Comment: Are you trying to delete the whole account, or just remove accounts from the multi-logon account chooser?

Answer (score 4):

1. Sign out of Google.
2. Click on the Sign in button. If an account chooser is shown, then

   1. Click on "Remove account" (it's a the bottom of the account list)
   2. Click on the X next to each account that you want to remove.
   3. Click on the Done button

Comment: That just removes the account from the account chooser. It doesn't actually delete the account.

Comment: @ale I don't think that the OP is talking "googlish"

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to the account you want to delete.

Go to [MyAccount.Google.com](https://myaccount.google.com).

Click on "[Delete your account or services](https://myaccount.google.com/preferences#deleteservices)" under Account Preferences.

Click "Delete Google Account and data". Confirm it's your account. Follow the rest of the process.

Your account will be inaccessible, and the data will be permanently gone in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to stop the browser suggesting/showing accounts that you can sign in to?
If you want to remove them from sign in options you will need to sign out first.
In the Chrome browser tab, click the key symbol.
This will bring up a list of the stored accounts for Google which you can delete.

[image: Chrome browser tab with highlighted key symbol]

Answer (score -1):

To delete the user from the Google

1. Sign in to Google Analytics
2. go to the account preferences
   2.1 In this section you can see below the option delete your account or services
   2.2 again click the delete account and data
   2.3 enter your password of that email account

3.then go to the below of the section where you can find the delete button on that and delete your account